# What are the lessons we can learn from the creation of عيسى (Jesus) PBUH?

Tags: tafseer, allah, prophet-isa, jews, surat-maryam

The Jews were people of faith and clinged to a strict hereditary practices of marriage based on strict constrained sexual contract.

They have achieved pinnacle status in doing so to the point of the adoption of مريم (Maryam/Marry) AS in their محراب (mi7rab/sanctuary/monastary) in order to preserve the status of sexual purity (احصان الفرج).

Yet Allah SWT showed the world a different path in the meaning of life by introducing عيسى 3eesa/Jesus to the world without the need of a fatherly figure to balance the motherly figure of Maryam AS.

Why would Allah SWT do such thing?
What is the message?

Why was Maryam accused of بغاء Bigha or بغيا Baghiyya, and what was Allah SWT answer to this accusation?

Answer (score 1):

The message of his creation I believe, and Allah knows best is like that of Adam's creation, that when Allah wants something all he has to say to it is "Be" and He does what He wants to do.

[image]

Indeed, the example of Jesus to Allah is like that of Adam. He created Him from dust; then He said to him, "Be," and he was.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would Allah SWT do such thing? What is the message?

Not only the fatherless birth of Jesus (pbuh) but also many other signs which Allah showed to Children of Israel were to attract the lost sheep of Israel back to God.

I can think of mainly 2 reasons.

1. These miracles i.e. fatherless birth, Jesus (pbuh) raising dead people, giving life to bird made of clay etc, these were the clear signs shown to those people, in a hope that they'll increase their belief in God.
2. To show that Allah can do anything, i.e. let even the impossible happen. And he is able to do all things.

> Why was Maryam accused of بغاء Bigha or بغيا Baghiyya?

Well just imagine today a woman conceiving a baby without any man touching her. It would be hard to believe ryt? So, similarly, the Jews at that time, didn't believe that she was gifted a baby directly from God, and rather accused her of having unlawful baby.

> what was Allah SWT answer to this accusation?

The answer is this...

> Therefore, for their (Jews) breaking their covenant and their disbelief in the communications of Allah and their killing the prophets wrongfully and their saying: Our **hearts** are covered; nay! **Allah set a seal upon them** owing **to their unbelief**, so they shall not believe except a few. (Qur'an 4:155)
>
> **And for their disbelief and their speaking against Maryam (Mary) a tremendous all-malicious (calumny).** (Qur'an 4:156)

May the creator guide us all.