# Is it permissible to rub my penis during a bath?

Tags: halal-haram, masturbation

I'm 17 years old male (not married). I'm just thinking about something that I do when I go for a bath, is it permissible to rub my penis during a bath with the intention of releasing semen and being lascivious? After that I wash my penis with clean water.

Comment: -1: don't they have sex education at your school?

Comment: @MoziburUllah What does sex education have to do with what Islam thinks about masturbation?

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you this is not permissible as it is the necessarily the same thing as masturbating.

*This is confirmed by the verses:*

> "And those who guard their chastity (i.e. private parts, from illegal
> sexual acts). Except from their wives or (the captives and slaves)
> that their right hands possess, - for them, they are free from blame.
> But whoever seeks beyond that, then those are the transgressors."
> (23:5-7)

Instead you should fast if you feel any sexual desires as you aren't married, this was recommended by the *Prophet SAW*.

Comment: What do you means

Comment: It means "don't do it, it is haram".

Answer (score 2):

These Qur'an ayat are interpreted as forbidding masturbation:

> And they who guard their private parts Except from their wives or those their [right hands possess](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/what-does-right-hand-possess-mean), for indeed, they will not be blamed - But whoever seeks beyond that, then those are the transgressors - ... -- [Qur'an 23:5-7](https://quran.com/23/5)

See e.g. fatawa: [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/329); [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Id=81167&Option=FatwaId); [AskImam.org](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/15975).  As such, the problem is not just uncleanliness, so the presence of absence of bath water makes no difference.

Comment: But this ayah is related to odalisques as described by your reference link, but not mentioning masturbation.