# Why Maria al-Qibtiyya(r.a) is considered as a slave?

Tags: slavery

I know those who claim Maria al-Qibtiyya(r.a) was slave believe she later became free after giving birth to prophet's(s.a) son

But my question is, was she slave before giving birth to prophet's son. Prior to Islam there were many sources of slave but after Islam only source of slave is captives captured in war or children of slaves. Maria was neither of them, she was gifted by a king and she belonged to a noble family in that place. https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%A8%D8%B7%D9%8A%D8%A9

Then why she is considered as slave ?

Comment: If you read the Article you linked you'll read that a part of the gift was الهدية جاريتين two female slaves, see also the english page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_al-Qibtiyya

Comment: Just because a king claim they are slaves, will it become slave for Muslim. isn't only source of slave being captured in war or children of slave ? in the article it is said, وكان أبوها عظيم من عظماء القبط . then how they became slaves

Comment: I'm not sure but in christian Europe it was easy to become a slave for example because you couldn't pay your bills! So if this is what you would like to have investigated good luck!

Comment: See also http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=150505&fromCat=624

Comment: the link says whether she was mother of believers or not but question was how she become slave in the first place as she was not obtained in war. it is said that war and being children of slave is only source of slave in Islam. As you said there were other sources before islam like not able to pay debt. But Maria came to prophet(s.a) life around the end of his life so Islamic rules would be applicable by then.

Comment: my assumption is that she is considered slave only and not a wife of prophet(s.a) by later Muslims so that sex without marriage with slave can be justified.

Comment: I know and I'm trying to understand this too!

Comment: The German wikipedia (which as far as i can tell) is the best sourced site of all says there's no single evidence that Muhammad ever married Maria al-Qibtiyya nor released her during his lifetime, they even question to some extent the fact that she converted.

Comment: [Did the prophet saw have sex slave](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62950/did-the-prophet-saw-have-a-sex-slave) clearly seems relevant here.

Comment: @Jamila after Islam only source of slave is captives captured in war or children of slaves, Maria (r.a) was not captured in war and not a child of slave, why she is still considered a slave ? that is my question

Comment: Who said that? In Islam one could turn a person into a slave this way anything else you've said is wrong.