# Was Mary the Copt married or a concubine to Prophet Muhammad (saw)?

Tags: hadith, history, wives-of-the-prophet

I would like know the status of Mary the Copt was she a concubine or did she marry and become one of the wives of Prophet Muhammad (saw)? There seems to be conflicting views about this and I would like a detailed answer.

Here the sources one says she was a concubine and the other argues she was a wife of the Prophet according the hadith about treading Egyptians kindly because of blood ties and marriage and imam Nawawi explanation of the hadith in his sharh says Mary was married to Prophet.

https://islamqa.info/en/47572

https://discover-the-truth.com/2016/07/20/maria-the-copt-wife-of-prophet-muhammed/

Comment: Similar question https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28795/why-maria-al-qibtiyyar-a-is-considered-as-a-slave

Comment: Sometimes you'll find readings that aren't derived from the texts themselves but are an extrapolation intended to show Muhammad in a positive light; that's my impression regarding the narratives surrounding Mary the Copt.

Comment: Not satisfied, question has gone unanswered and the link Medi1Saif didn't explain anything there was no answer.