# What is meant by "concubines" in this hadith?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Assalamualikumwarahmatullah to all, just need quick clarification on this hadith please

> "I noticed that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) was missing from bed, so I started to look for him, and I thought that he had gone to one of his **concubines**. Then my hand fell on him when he was prostrating and saying: "Allahummaghfirli ma asrartu wa ma a'lant (O Allah, forgive me for what (sin) I have concealed and what I have done openly).'
>
> reference   : [Sunan an-Nasa'i 1124](https://sunnah.com/nasai:1124)
> In-book reference   : Book 12, Hadith 96
> English translation     : Vol. 2, Book 12, Hadith 1125

What is meant by the word "concubines" does it mean "wives" or something else, any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Concubine itself means female-slaves. But somehow at the hadith website in my native language they translated the hadith you're referring to with "wives". I think you may need a direct arabic translation to get the best answer

Answer (score 3):

جواري is the plural of جارية  and can mean a young woman or a female slave.

In this hadith it is possible that it means 'concubines', who are female slaves with whom sexual relations are lawful, see [Did the Prophet (SAW) have a sex slave?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62950/).

However it is also possible that 'wives' is meant here, as the word can be used for them and there is a version that uses a synonym:

> فظننت أنه ذهب إلى بعض نسائه
>
> I thought that he had gone to one of his (other) wives.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:485) and [Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai:1131)</sup>

Ref: [شرح سنن النسائي](https://ia800203.us.archive.org/30/items/WAQ87761/shsuns13.pdf#page=371)