# Sex with slave women

Tags: sex, slavery, consent

We all know that Islam allows having sex with female slaves outside of marriage. My question is what are the conditions to have sex with the female slaves? If she does not want to have sex with the master, does the master have the authority to force her to have sex? As per this [document][1], it is mentioned that "Despite this protection against one form of sexual exploitation, female slaves do not have the right to grant or deny sexual access to themselves."

[1]: [https://www.brandeis.edu/projects/fse/muslim/slavery.html#:~:text=Despite%20this%20protection%20against%20one,6%3B%2070.29%2D30](https://www.brandeis.edu/projects/fse/muslim/slavery.html#:%7E:text=Despite%20this%20protection%20against%20one,6%3B%2070.29%2D30)).

Comment: As for the conditions see https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62950/ and https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/26399/20218 etc.