# Hadith explanation Sunan An Nasai 3959

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Sunan An Nasai 3959. This has not weakened my Iman at all I just want context on what the hadith actually means

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did the Prophet (SAW) have a sex slave?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62950/did-the-prophet-saw-have-a-sex-slave)

Comment: A referenze number of hadith doesn't reveal its content since the original books had no reference number only in modern edition editors created their own count. Mainky the same applies to the qur'an as there are different verse counts, but since most online editions refer to the most used kufi count it is much safer to use it as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

The prophet Muhammad did have a sex-slave according to that Hadith:

Sunan an-Nasa'i 3959
It was narrated from Anas, that the Messenger of Allah had a female slave with whom he had intercourse, but 'Aishah and Hafsah would not leave him alone until he said that she was forbidden for him. Then Allah, the Mighty and Sublime, revealed:
"O Prophet! Why do you forbid (for yourself) that which Allah has allowed to you.' until the end of the Verse.