# Is having sexual relations with a mahram permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, mahram

If can look and touch a mahram then why can't I enjoy sexual realations as well? please provide specific evidence to support your answer.

Comment: @Uma I updated it to make it more sincere.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin I don't really know if that's proper, you've removed the reasoning that the question used to arrive at the assumption.

Comment: Ahmed please provide what you have found during your researches

Comment: wt... What do you mean by **casual play**? I'm really stunned...! **Incest**? Is that what you mean! You must define **CASUAL PLAY**. What types of sexual acts can be termed as **casual**? Are there any sexual acts that we casually do?

Comment: can some one please suggest to me how i may be able to fix this question as not to get unblocked from asking questions?

Comment: You cannot edit a question to change almost all of its content as this may render answers below inapplicable. I have rolled back your edits.

Comment: i have been blocked from asking any more questions. as a suggestion the help page asks i edit my questions in order to get unblocked any way you mightbe able to assist?

Comment: The question seems odd, considering that your spouse is Mahram to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I got your question correctly, but I believe you will find your answer (a reference for tahreem) in Surat Al-Nisaa (Chapter 4) Verse (Aaya) #4, and I quote it here:

"
Prohibited to you [for marriage] are your mothers, your daughters, your sisters, your father's sisters, your mother's sisters, your brother's daughters, your sister's daughters, your [milk] mothers who nursed you, your sisters through nursing, your wives' mothers, and your step-daughters under your guardianship [born] of your wives unto whom you have gone in. But if you have not gone in unto them, there is no sin upon you. And [also prohibited are] the wives of your sons who are from your [own] loins, and that you take [in marriage] two sisters simultaneously, except for what has already occurred. Indeed, Allah is ever Forgiving and Merciful.
"

https://quran.com/4/23

Comment: Try adding references

Answer (score 16):

*Mahram* is derived from *haram*, it literally means "forbidden people", i.e. people with whom sex and marriage is forbidden.

According to the Quran, sex is only permitted with one's wives and female slaves([1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/649/are-muslim-men-allowed-to-take-sex-slaves/20237),[2](https://islamqa.info/en/13737)):

> [Quran 23:5-6](https://quran.com/23/5) And they who guard their private parts. Except from
>   their wives or those their right hands possess, for indeed, they will
>   not be blamed.

Also according to the Quran, marriage with mahrams is forbidden:

> [Quran 4:23](https://quran.com/4/23) Prohibited to you [for marriage] are your mothers,
>   your daughters, your sisters, your father's sisters, your mother's
>   sisters, your brother's daughters, your sister's daughters, your
>   [milk] mothers who nursed you, your sisters through nursing, your
>   wives' mothers, and your step-daughters under your guardianship [born]
>   of your wives unto whom you have gone in. But if you have not gone in
>   unto them, there is no sin upon you. And [also prohibited are] the
>   wives of your sons who are from your [own] loins, and that you take
>   [in marriage] two sisters simultaneously, except for what has already
>   occurred. Indeed, Allah is ever Forgiving and Merciful.

Since a Mahram is a close relative and a close part of one's household, it is permitted to look at them and to touch them when necessary (on the face, arms, etc.) Looking at and touching the private parts is not permitted, and touching anywhere with desire is also not permitted.

Section on Looking and touching mahrams in the [Hidayah](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.216460/2015.216460.The-Hedaya#page/n615/mode/2up):

> A man may look at the person of his kinswoman. IT is lawful for a man
>   to look at his female relation either in the face, head, breast,
>   shoulder, or legs : for as it is usual with relations to visit one
>   another without any previous intimation, and unattended with any
>   retinue, and as women, in their house, generally wear a dress adapted
>   to service, if, therefore, the sight of these parts were culpable, it
>   would impose too great restraint upon them. It is different with
>   respect to other parts ; and hence proceeds the illegality of looking
>   at the back or belly. (It Is proper to observe that by the term
>   relation [Mohrim], as here used, it to be under stood  any person
>   between whom and the beholder marriage is utterly and perpetually
>   illegal, in consequence of affinity by either blood or marriage )
>
> Male and female relations may touch each other (if there be no
>   apprehension of passion.) EVERY part in a relation which it is lawful
>   to look at may likewise be touched ; unless, however, there be a dread
>   of its inflaming the passion of either, in which case neither the
>   sight nor the touch is approved.

Additional reference: *Awrah* in front of Mahrams [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/82994).

Answer (score 4):

Others have given enough of references which are very good. I'll try to give a rational answer.

Same can be said for a 4 year old girl. You can touch her, so why not have non-penetrative sex with her in her sleep? 
There is a natural shame in doing it (There may also be a desire, but still the shame is there). Same shame exists for your mahrams. The only difference with mahrams is it's consensual and with an adult.

Additionally:

- It would make **inheritance** complicated. A sister may also be a mother, etc.
- Families would be in contact with a smaller population and learn less from others. It's like them living in their own village. (Normally people/groups who only marry their own kind/group have a lower level of tolerance for othering. The more diverse you more you're adaptable you become and more you can understand others. (I don't mean accept everyone, but some differences make total sense, some make zero sense) If you move to a new city you learn something new, if you learn a new language you learn something new, if you marry a different person you learn something new. But with with incest you're planting a seed of **social restriction** onto yourself and your children.)
- It's not the way Allah wants. I mean you can eat a sheep that has been slaughtered halal. For it to be slaughtered halal you must say bismillah before. If you don't then the meat is haram. For a marriage you must say certain words before. If not it's haram, it's zina. And it's not like these certain words are just for the sake of a checkbox, no when you say these things there spiritual effects taking place. As a Muslim we should believe in the unseen. Marrying your own mahram has certain **unseen affects**.
- There are genetic concerns. Inbreeding which is very similar creates many **genetic issues**. See [here](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/women/mother-tongue/4014743/Warning-over-births-to-first-cousin-marriages.html) and [here](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/religion/7497906/Baroness-Deech-Risks-of-cousin-marriage-not-discussed-for-fear-of-offending-Muslims.html) Now imagine if this happens 2-3 generations in. The effect would be magnified. From the article it says:

> However it is estimated that 55 per cent of British Pakistanis are
>   married to first cousins, and a third of children with recessive
>   genetic disorders are born to that community.

So to conclude it's to be avoided for complications in inheritance, creating social restrictions, it won't have Allah's blessing, genetic issues.

Comment: _"There is a natural shame in doing it"_ Do you have any backup for that? As far as my observations go, the ability to feel ashamed is something you are born with but what you actually feel shame for heavily depends on the culture/the people around you. If you are referring to what Islam wants you to be ashamed for that should be made clear. The point about less contact with others is flimsy. What prevents you from travelling/moving around and interacting with people? _"some differences make total sense, some make zero sense"_ What do you mean?

Comment: @TheRavenQueen shame comes from our universal nature + different cultures. By 'universal' I mean it's not bound to Islam. It's one of the things that is closely agreed by theists and atheists (there are some rare exceptions, there are some exceptions who do many other wrong things). "Some difference..."<-- I mean experiencing differences among people is usually a good thing, different cultures respect their elder, show hospitality differently, though some differences like worshipping the devil, pedophilia, *total* support of every kind of abortion aren't good and don't deserve respect.

Comment: "_closely agreed by theists and atheists"_ Then surely you can provide references? All I could find with a quick google search were un-scientific posts with the same observation I made which would contradict that notion. Also be careful to not inject your opinion into answers or comments. If Islam holds a certain position that can be backed up then that's one thing. Saying "X is bad" without that context is an opinion and not objectively/universally true. Some parts of your answer fall into that category or at least aren't as clearly worded as they should be.

Comment: Atheists and theist agree that rape is bad. That abortion is generally despised. No pro-choice person feels happy when the abort, it’s just a necessity. That showing love to your parents is good. That helping the poor is and showing kinds to humans is good

Answer (score -1):

SubhanAllah, Allah Pak  in Quran said it clearly that it's not permissible to marry your mother, sister or any kind of mehram. Quran 4:23. Allah Pak knew it that it's not possible for you to have normal child with them, so Allah Pak marked it has haram. Now science tells us that we cannot have normal children with our Mehrams. SubhanAllah, Allah has all the knowledge of what we can't even think.. My brother seek for forgiveness if you ever had sexual thoughts about your Mehrams. There are millions of other muslims girls other than your Mehrams who will InshAllah marry you and with her you can live a respectable life and have healthy children InshAllah. May Allah Pak bless you..