# What rulings of polygny apply in the case of a free man marrying a slave girl?

Tags: nikah, fiqh, tafseer, husband-wife, slavery

After reading [Did scholars define a limitation of concubines a man could have?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50176/did-scholars-define-a-limitation-of-concubines-a-man-could-have) I remembered that there's another verse later saying:

> And whoever among you cannot [find] the means to marry free, believing women, then [he may marry] from those whom your right hands possess of believing slave girls. ... ([4:25](https://legacy.quran.com/4/25))

This verse is discussing the situation of a man who wants to get married, but for some reason can't afford marrying a free woman. This made me curious about this situation and relevant rulings.

I have a couple of questions concerning this marriage, but before making this post to broad let me start by asking this:

- When it comes to polygyny -maybe the husband becomes wealthy after marrying a slave- which rules apply in case of a further marriage those of a marriage with a free women or those of a concubinage?
  And if so would it make a difference if among the possibly other wife was free?

Comment: Which does the man intend to do? Marry her or just be with her as concubinage? Depending on what he intends the rules become different. Your question is no different from I intend to put my money in the bank which gives interest. Now do the rules of قرض الحسنه apply to me? Apparently no! But you won't be asking such a simple question so I guess I'm missing something...

Comment: @Honey I'm clearly referring to the marriage not concubinage.

Comment: Then the rules of marriage apply between them. That being said just a side note. AFAIK 1400 years ago no slave women was just (unwilingly) handed to a man. The woman had to accept the man. Otherwise it would be rape. That being said she would have very limited social status as a slave women without a man. Hence 99% of the women just chose the man they liked. It was extremely cruel to them. I'm thankful me and my  family were not born in that era...My whole point is that the major rule which is **her consent** still applied.

Comment: @Honey certainly I just needed to adjust my question because parts of my first attempt were answered in a different post.

Comment: _in case of a further marriage_ what does 'further' mean? As in you have a  concubinage and then want to do a permanent marriage?

Comment: @Honey no if you wanted to marry a second woman ... In the sunni view marrying the slave of somebody else is permissible under certain conditions but seems disliked if I remember well the shi'a view is against slave concubinage in means no relation without marriage is that correct?

Comment: I don't know. This is a domain I don't have knowledge about. Would have to do some research. But usually I don't because it does seem applicable for me and our era :)

Comment: There are narrations from Shia hadith that say that a man cannot marry a slave-girl if he has married a free woman first. https://thaqalayn.net/chapter/5/3/34