# slave woman becoming her master's 5th wife?

Tags: women, husband-wife, slavery, freedom

a slave woman in islam can become her master's wife in some conditions but what if the master already have 4 wives and the condition for the slave to be wife arrived? will she become 5th wife? if she became wouln't it became against law?

Comment: There's no such thing like a condition for a slave girl becoming her masters wife except with her to be freed first.

Comment: This question shows a clear misunderstanding a master must free his slave ifrst before marying her. In other words if he freed her and had 4 wives he can't have a fifth wife. A slave girl however can be a wife another man if her master agrees to such a marriage.

Answer (score 2):

No, a slave woman can not become the 5th 'wife' of her master. Your question has several misunderstandings:

- **Concubinage** and **Marriage** are two different things. A concubine is not a wife. A concubine is a slave woman with whom sex is permissible because of ownership alone, without requiring any nikah contract.

  > And they who guard their private parts. Except from their **wives** or **those their right hands possess** (concubines), for indeed, they will not be blamed.
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 23:5-6](https://quran.com/23/5-7)</sup>
- There is only a legal limit on the number of wives. There is no limit on the number of concubines. So for example a person can hypothetically have 4 wives and 10 concubines, and it would be legal. See [Did scholars define a limitation of concubines a man could have?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50176/)
- A marriage contract with a concubine is actually not permissible for her owner. If the master wants to marry his concubine he would first have to free her.

  > لا يحتاج وطء السيد لأمته إلى إنشاء عقد زواج، ولو عقد النكاح لنفسه على مملوكته لم يصح النكاح
  >
  > A Marriage contract is not required if a master wishes to have sexual relations with his female slave. And if he makes a marriage contract between himself and his female slave it is not valid.
  >
  > <sup>— [Encyclopedia of Islamic Jurisprudence 11/297](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/6868)</sup>