# Is slavery allowed in islam?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy, slavery

Is slavery allowed in Islam if yes,can I own a slave today?
Please explain me in detailed. Explain why this is the case also:Why islam didn't ban slavery even if it is a very bad system?

Comment: To answer your question of "can I own a slave now?": If you can find a legitimate source of slaves as in prisoners of war from the Jihad of an Islamic Caliph, you can own slaves. If not, making free people into slaves is completely forbidden in Islam.

Comment: Salam ad welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Note that your inquiry is also addressed in my answer on [Are Muslim men allowed to take sex slaves?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/649/are-muslim-men-allowed-to-take-sex-slaves/26399#26399).