# Some questions about slavery in Islam

Tags: slavery

1. Could masters force a female slave to have sex with them if they did not want to?
2. Could a master forcefully marry his slave?
3. What is the legal status of a child between a slave and her master?
4. Is a master obligated to write a contract of manumission with his slave if the slave wanted it?
5. What happens if the slave is married before he?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. These are too many questions in one post. Please consider editing and splitting your post. Some of these questions are already answered on the site. See for example [Are Muslims allowed to have sex slaves](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/649/are-muslim-men-allowed-to-take-sex-slaves) in my answer most of your questions are covered.

Comment: @Medi1Saif i have seen your answer [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/649/are-muslim-men-allowed-to-take-sex-slaves) but i don't see there any clear answer to this person's Question number 1. Master can't force their slaves to prostitution. But the question here, can the master forcefully sex with his slave even if she don't want it?

Comment: @Yusha actually the first question you pretend not being answered is the topic of that post my answer is about.

Comment: @Medi1Saif If i saw it right, The topic was if muslim men allowed to have sex slaves. your answer is it is allowed in certain circumstances. But what if the slave don't want to do sex with the master, can the master force her to sex? that's the question.

Comment: @Yusha and that is addressed and answered there

Comment: @Medi1Saif OK i honestly can't find that there.If you could kindly copy paste that part here. if it's not possible in comment section. you can paste it in this [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115199/slavery)

Comment: @Yusha the part is that in which I'm answering the question and it has a clear corresponding title.