# Were concubines able to reject the master?

Tags: history, slavery, freedom

A short question.
This is more a historical issue.

Is it consensus by the scholars that a concubine can reject sexual intercourse with his master, if she does not want it?

Thanks for responses.

Comment: "reject" needs to be detailed see my answer on [Are Muslim men allowed to have sex slaves](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/649/are-muslim-men-allowed-to-take-sex-slaves) maybe it already covers your inquiry.

Answer (score -3):

Concubinage is a legal relationship akin to marriage between a female slave and a free man. For we have:

> As they say 'a concubine', the origin is from 'concubinage', which is marriage

and

> Concubinage, from the root *sirr* meaning secret, is marriage because it is kept hidden ... The concubine is the servant girl under the custodian of the master with whom she is intimate

Both quotes are from *Lisan al-Arab*. Given this, I would take  Hadith applying to marriage would apply. In *Sahih al-Bukhari*, there is a report of a marriage proposal to the Prophet but when the Prophet sees the woman, she says she 'takes refuge in Allah'. That is, whilst her household had made the proposal, she herself is not keen. The Hadith ends with the Prophet giving her a gift and sending her away.

Hence, I would say a concubine can legally refuse.

Note: Although I'm a scholar, I'm not an accredited Hadith scholar. So use at your own risk.