# Can a Muslim man take a concubine who's neither a Christian nor a Jew?

Tags: nikah, slavery, interfaith

It's well known that, according to the orthodox Islam, a Muslim man can marry only with a Muslim woman, or a Christian woman, or a Jewish woman.

Does this restriction apply to concubines? For example, can a Muslim man take a concubine who's an atheist, or a polytheist, or an agnostic etc. ?

Comment: This was addressed in my answer on [Can Muslim man have sex slaves](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/649/13438)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is difference among the madhabs on this. The view of the majority is that it is not permitted - a concubine of a Muslim must be either Muslim, Jewish or Christian. Their evidence includes:

> ولا تنكحوا المشركات حتى يؤمن
>
> And do not marry polytheistic women until they believe
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:221](https://quran.com/2/221?translations=20)</sup>

The word نكاح  applies to both contractual marriage or sexual intercourse and so is inclusive of relations through ownership of a slave.

The second madhab is that it is permitted. They have relied upon the hadith of the expedition of Awtas, where the sahaba made concubines of women of the polytheists, and it is probable that they were polytheists at that time.

> عن أبي سعيد الخدري،  أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم يوم حنين بعث جيشا إلى أوطاس، فلقوا عدوا، فقاتلوهم فظهروا عليهم، وأصابوا لهم سبايا، فكأن ناسا من أصحاب رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم تحرجوا من غشيانهن من أجل أزواجهن من المشركين، فأنزل الله عز وجل في ذلك: {والمحصنات من النساء إلا ما ملكت أيمانكم} [النساء: 24]، أي: فهن لكم حلال إذا انقضت عدتهن
>
> It was narrated from Abu Sa'eed Al-Khudri that on the Day of Hunain, the Messenger of Allah sent an army to Awtas, where they met the enemy, fought them and prevailed over them. They captured some female prisoners, and it was as if the Companions of the Messenger of Allah felt reluctant to have intercourse with them because of their idolater husbands. Then Allah, the Mighty and Sublime, revealed: "Also (forbidden are) women already married, except those (slaves) whom your right hands possess",' meaning, they are permissible for you once their 'Iddah has ended.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/17/41)</sup>

**Reference:**

> [الفصل الثاني من حرم نكاح حرائرهم من المجوسيات وغيرهم لا يباح وطء
> الإماء منهن بملك اليمين]
>
> الفصل الثاني: أن من حرم نكاح حرائرهم من المجوسيات، وسائر الكوافر سوى
> أهل الكتاب، لا يباح وطء الإماء منهن بملك اليمين. في قول أكثر أهل
> العلم، منهم؛ مرة الهمداني، والزهري، وسعيد بن جبير، والأوزاعي، والثوري،
> وأبو حنيفة، ومالك، والشافعي. وقال ابن عبد البر: على هذا جماعة فقهاء
> الأمصار، وجمهور العلماء، وما خالفه فشذوذ لا يعد خلافا. ولم يبلغنا
> إباحة ذلك إلا عن طاوس، ووجه قوله عموم قوله تعالى {والمحصنات من النساء
> إلا ما ملكت أيمانكم} [النساء: 24] .
>
> والآية الأخرى.
>
> وروى أبو سعيد، «أن رسول الله - صلى الله عليه وسلم - بعث يوم حنين بعثا
> قبل أوطاس، فأصابوا لهم سبايا، فكأن ناسا من أصحاب رسول الله - صلى الله
> عليه وسلم - تحرجوا من غشيانهن، من أجل أزواجهن من المشركين، فأنزل الله
> عز وجل في ذلك {والمحصنات من النساء إلا ما ملكت أيمانكم} [النساء: 24] .
> قال: فهن لهم حلال إذا انقضت عدتهن.» وعنه «، أن رسول الله - صلى الله
> عليه وسلم - قال في سبايا أوطاس: لا توطأ حامل حتى تضع، ولا غير ذات حمل
> حتى تحيض حيضة» . رواهما أبو داود. وهو حديث صحيح. وهم عبدة أوثان.
>
> وهذا ظاهر في إباحتهن، ولأن الصحابة في عصر النبي - صلى الله عليه وسلم -
> كان أكثر سباياهم من كفار العرب، وهم عبدة أوثان، فلم يكونوا يرون
> تحريمهن لذلك، ولا نقل عن النبي - صلى الله عليه وسلم - تحريمهن، ولا أمر
> الصحابة باجتنابهن، وقد دفع أبو بكر إلى سلمة بن الأكوع امرأة من بعض
> السبي، نفلها إياه، وأخذ عمر وابنه من سبي هوازن، وكذلك غيرهما من
> الصحابة، والحنفية أم محمد ابن الحنفية من سبي بني حنيفة، وقد أخذ
> الصحابة سبايا فارس، وهم مجوس، فلم يبلغنا أنهم اجتنبوهن، وهذا ظاهر في
> إباحتهن، لولا اتفاق أهل العلم على خلافه.
>
> وقد أجبت عن حديث أبي سعيد بأجوبة، منها أنه يحتمل أنهن أسلمن، كذلك روي
> عن أحمد أنه سأله محمد بن الحكم قال: قلت لأبي عبد الله: هوازن أليس
> كانوا عبدة أوثان؟ قال: لا أدري كانوا أسلموا أو لا. وقال ابن عبد البر:
> إباحة وطئهن منسوخة بقوله تعالى {ولا تنكحوا المشركات حتى يؤمن} [البقرة:
> 221] .
>
> <sup>— [المغني لابن قدامة](https://al-maktaba.org/book/8463/2943#p1)</sup>