# Can a slave have multiple owners at the same time?

Tags: sharia, slavery

I'm aware having a slave is permitted. However, can a slave have multiple owners at the same time?

If yes, I'm particularly curious of the case for concubines. For example, if a concubine becomes pregnant while having multiple owners, are all the owners responsible for taking care of the baby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of inheritance for example a slave (or more) could be part of the shares of multiple heirs. The same may happen in case of a business with partners.

In such a case it is not permissible for any of the owners to have intercourse  with a concubine as none of them has an exclusive ownership and sharing her would be equal to practicing fornication or zina. I've already pointed at that in my answer about whether a Muslim may have sex slaves: [Are Muslim men allowed to take "sex slaves?"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/649/are-muslim-men-allowed-to-take-sex-slaves)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.