# Akhi I Recently Read This Article On Quora That Muslims Force Captives To Have Coitus Interruptus

Tags: fiqh, sunni, hanafi, maliki

[Source of the claim](https://exmuslimsassemble.quora.com/https-exmuslimsassemble-quora-com-Can-a-master-rape-his-female-slave-captives-and-can-a-husband-rape-his-wives?ch=15&oid=148500083&share=c6efd7a2&srid=3rg4XI&target_type=post)

> It was narrated that: .' The messenger of Allah said: 'Do not do that. If I were to command anyone to prostrate to anyone other than Allah, I would have commanded women to prostrate to their husbands. By the One in Whose Hand is the soul of Muhammad! No woman can fulfill her duty towards Allah until she fulfills her duty towards her husband. If he asks her (for intimacy) even if she is on her camel saddle, she should not refuse.'  ([Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:1853))

Akhi This Article Shows The References From The Predominant Views Of The Hanafi , Shafi ,Maliki Schools I Am Having Doubt Regarding This Can Anyone Clarify

Jazakallah Khair

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept such as consent in Islām when it comes to slaves. The female-slave must obey her master because she is his property.

Read this link:

https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/77914/58155