# What happens if a slave woman refuses to have intercourse with the master

Tags: sex, slavery

If she shows discontent or outright refusal to the masters’ advances for intercourse can he force her? Does he discipline or repremind her for disobedience? If so what measures does he take to discipline her?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is consent necessary for sexual relations with a concubine?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/is-consent-necessary-for-sexual-relations-with-a-concubine)

Comment: @UmH my question is a follow up to that. I’m aware consent isn’t a legal requirement to make intimacy halal.

Comment: The answer already says that that he can force and disciple her by punishing her.

Comment: @UmH sorry I didnt see that. What are acceptable ways of discipline? Is it the same as with a wife that he can beat her lightly?

Comment: Yes the means are the same as ta'zeer or punishing wives or children.

Comment: Okay thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

It is permissible to force wives as well as slave girls if they don't provide any legitimate Shari excuse for refusing sexual intercourse as per Radd Al Mukhtar but it doesn't mean He should harm.

Slave girls should be disciplined in the same manner as wives are disciplined but if she insists not to copulate then he must sell her.

Comment: What is meant by not harming her. Isn't forcing a wife/slave in bed despite their resistance, screaming,  a form of harm?

Comment: When scholars used the word "force" they didn't meant the physical force as we have build in our mind due to western indoctrination. Rather it refers to verbal ways of reminding them your rights.

Answer (score -2):

No, she cannot be forced to have sex. Forced sex is rape and it is forbidden.

> Say, "My Lord has only forbidden immoralities - what is apparent of
> them and what is concealed - and sin, and **oppression without right**,
> and that you associate with Allah that for which He has not sent down
> authority, and that you say about Allah that which you do not know."
> Quran 7:33