# can you separate a female captive's husband from her if there both captured

Tags: slavery, jihad

I know that when you captive prisoners of war thats married there divorce by being captured. If there capture with there husband then would they still be married and if so would it be permissible to seperate them or force a divorce.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is intercourse allowed with already married captives?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/73437/is-intercourse-allowed-with-already-married-captives)

Comment: @UmH In your answer you typed "Her husband was also captured and imprisoned alongside her. In this case, the view of the majority is that any previous marriage is annulled. While the view of the Hanafis and some others is that the marriage is retained."  So this means they are separated from one another and are divorced.

Answer (score 0):

The condition as per Fuqaha is women being captured first and alone for dissolving the marriage.

Otherwise, if both are captured or the husband is captured first and alone then her wife is captured and the dissolution of the marriage doesn't occur.