# The Devshrime system implemented by Ottoman Empire was it Halal or Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, sharia, history, usool-ul-fiqh

[Are Muslim men allowed to take "sex slaves?"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/649/are-muslim-men-allowed-to-take-sex-slaves)

As stated in the above answer there are only two ways a free person can be enslaved.

It's if they become prisoners of war or if they are born to slave parents.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devshirme

And from the above link what appears to be the case is that Ottoman Empire had this system of enslaving free dhimmis which as far as I know is not allowed in Islam.And many western writers did say it was not allowed but I wanted an scholarly view on this matter from an Islamic scholar.

Was this matter allowed in Islam or was it prohibited but Ottomans did it anyway?

Comment: Ottoman royals were Muslims only on paper. Each time a prince ascended to the throne he ordered his brothers to be killed disregarding their ages in order to prevent a future rebellion by them. So I wouldn't be surprised if Devshirme system was also haram