# Is prophet Muhammad's "Last Sermon" an accurate translation?

Tags: translation, prophet-muhammad, books

[The poorly-cited Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Farewell_Sermon) states:

> The Farewell Sermon (Arabic: خطبة الوداع‎, Khuṭbatu l-Wadā), also
>   known as Muhammad's Final Sermon or The Last Sermon, was delivered by
>   Muhammad on the 9th of Dhu al-Hijjah, 10 AH (9 March 632) in the
>   Uranah valley of Mount Arafat.

[This page](http://www.islam-watch.org/authors/89-other-authors/134-fraudulent-translation-of-muhammad-last-sermon-egalitarian.html) states that his famed "Last Sermon" is a fake from 1991.

The top of 4.630.000 Google results for "[last sermon](https://www.google.nl/search?q=last+sermon)" are indeed unsourced.

As [my last Facebook comment quoting it](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3857469006279&set=a.1273801416204.2032216.1564999382&type=1) got [censored without comment](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3857468566268&set=a.1273801416204.2032216.1564999382&type=1), I'd like to know whether that part ("You will neither inflict nor suffer any inequity.") was representative of the religion of Islam.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Farewell Sermon (as it is also known) can be found in all the major biographies of the prophet Mohammad such as *"Al Seerah Annabawiyah"* by Ibn Hisham.

The second link isn't saying that the sermon itself is fake, rather that the translation quoted in the article is erroneous and skewed. And in a way, they are right.

> “All mankind is from Adam and Eve, an Arab has no superiority over a
>   non-Arab nor a non-Arab has any superiority over an Arab; also a white
>   has no superiority over a black nor a black has any superiority over
>   white except by piety and good action. Learn that every Muslim is a
>   brother to every Muslim and that the Muslims constitute one
>   brotherhood. Nothing shall be legitimate to a Muslim which belongs to
>   a fellow Muslim unless it was given freely and willingly. Do not,
>   therefore, do injustice to yourselves."

This paragraph for instance has no word-to-word equivalent in the original sermon. While the original does state "All mankind is from Adam and Eve, an Arab has no superiority over a non-Arab nor a non-Arab has any superiority over an Arab" there is no mention of "white has no superiority over a black nor a black has any superiority over white", and so on.

I'm still searching for a better more accurate translation to English.

Coming to your third point, "You will neither inflict nor suffer any inequity." is indeed part of the Farwell Sermon. The Arabic equivalent is "لا تَظلمون ولا تُظلمون".

For reference, here is the full text of the sermon in Arabic (I may translate it myself later if I can't find a good sourced translation):

> الحمدُ لله نحمدُهُ وَنَسْتَعِينُه، ونَسْتَغْفِرُهُ، ونَتُوبُ إليه،
>   ونَعُوذُ باللهِ مِنْ شُرورِ أنْفُسِنا ومِنْ سيّئآتِ أعْمَالِنَا مَن
>   يَهْدِ اللهُ فَلا مُضِلَّ لَهُ، ومَنْ يُضَلِلْ فَلاَ هَادِيَ لَهُ .
>   وأشهد أن لا إله إلاّ الله وحْده لا شريك له، وأنّ محمداً عبدُه ورسولُه.
>   أوصيكُم عبادَ الله بتقوى الله،وأحثّكم على طاعته! 
>   وأستفتح بالذي هو خير.
>   أَمَّا بعد، أيّهَا النّاس، 
>   اسْمَعُوا منّي أُبّينْ لَكُمْ، فَإنّيَ لاَ
>   أَدْرِي، لعَليّ لاَ أَلْقَاكُمْ بَعْدَ عَامي هَذَا، في مَوْقِفي هذا،
>   أَيُهَا النَّاس، إنّ دِمَاءَكُمْ وَأمْوَالَكُمْ وَأَعْرَاضَكُمْ
>   عَليكُمْ حَرَامٌ إلى أنْ تَلْقَوْا رَبَّكُمْ، كَحُرمَةِ يَوْمِكُمْ
>   هَذَا في شَهْرِ كُمْ هَذَا في بَلَدِكُم هَذَا وإنكم ستلقون ربكم
>   فيسألكم عن أعمالكم وقد بلغت ، فَمَنْ كَانَتْ عِنْدَهُ أَمَانةٌ
>   فليؤُدِّها إلى مَنْ ائْتمَنَهُ عَلَيها، وإن كل ربا موضوع ولكن لكم رءوس
>   أموالكم لا تظلمون ولا تظلمون ، و قضى الله أنه لا ربا ، وإن ربا عمي
>   العباس بن عبد المطلب موضوع كله وأن كل دم كان في الجاهلية موضوع وإن أول
>   دمائكم أضع دم عامر ابن ربيعة بن الحارث بن عبد المطلب ، فهو أول ما أبدأ
>   به من دماء الجاهلية ، وإن مآثر الجاهلية موضوعة غير السدانة والسقاية
>   والعمد قَوَدٌ ، وشبه العمد ما قتل بالعصا والحجر وفيه مائة بعير فمن
>   ازداد فهو من الجاهلية.
>   أما بعد أيها الناس فإن الشيطان قد يئس من أن
>   يعبد بأرضكم هذه أبدا ولكنه إن يطع فيما سوى ذلك فقد رضي به بما تحقرون
>   من أعمالكم فاحذروه على دينكم أيها الناس ﴿ إِنَّمَا النَّسِيءُ
>   زِيَادَةٌ فِي الْكُفْرِ يُضَلُّ بِهِ الَّذِينَ كَفَرُوا يُحِلُّونَهُ
>   عَاماً وَيُحَرِّمُونَهُ عَاماً لِيُوَاطِئُوا عِدَّةَ مَا حَرَّمَ
>   اللَّهُ فَيُحِلُّوا مَا حَرَّمَ اللَّهُ ﴾ إن الزمان قد استدار كهيئته
>   يوم خلق الله السموات والأرض و﴿ إِنَ عِدَّةَ الشهور عند اللَّهِ اثْنَا
>   عَشَرَ شَهْراً ﴾ منها أربعة حرم ثلاثة متوالية ورجب مضر ، الذي بين
>   جمادى وشعبان.
>   أما بعد أيها الناس ، إن لِنسَائِكُمْ عَلَيْكُمْ حقاً،
>   ولَكُمْ عَلَيْهِنّ حقّ، لَكُمْ عَليِنّ ألا يُوطْئنَ فُرُشَكُمْ غيرَكم
>   وَلا يُدْخِلْنَ أحَداً تكرَهُونَهُ بيوتَكُمْ، ولا يأتينَ بِفَاحِشَة
>   فإن فعلن فإن الله قد أذن لكم أن تهجروهن في المضاجع وتضربوهن ضربا غير
>   مبرح فإن انتهين فلهن رزقهن وكسوتهن بالمعروف واستوصوا بالنساء خيرا ،
>   فإنهن عندكم عوان لا يملكن لأنفسهن شيئا ، وإنكم إنما أخذتموهن بأمانة
>   الله واستحللتم فروجهن بكلمات الله فاعقلوا أيها الناس قولي ، أَيهَا
>   النّاسُ، إنّما المُؤمِنُونَ إخْوةٌ ، فَلاَ يَحِلُّ لامْرِىءٍ مَالُ
>   أَخيهِ إلاّ عَنْ طيبِ نفْسٍ منهُ، أَلاَ هَلْ بلّغْتُ، اللّهُم اشْهَدْ،
>   فلا تَرْجِعُنّ بَعْدِي كُفاراً يَضرِبُ بَعْضُكُمْ رقابَ بَعْض فَإنّي
>   قَدْ تَركْتُ فِيكُمْ مَا إنْ أخَذتمْ بِهِ لَمْ تَضِلُّوا بَعْدَهُ،
>   كِتَابَ اللهِ وَ سُنَّة نَبيّه ، أَلاَ هَلْ بلّغتُ، اللّهمّ اشْهَدْ.
>   أيها النّاسُ إن رَبَّكُمْ وَاحِدٌ، وإنّ أَبَاكُمْ واحِدٌ ، كُلكُّمْ
>   لآدمَ وآدمُ من تُراب، إن أَكرمُكُمْ عندَ اللهِ أتْقَاكُمْ وليس لعربيّ
>   فَضْلٌ على عجميّ إلاّ بالتّقْوىَ، أَلاَ هَلْ بلَّغْتُ، اللّهُمّ اشهد"
>   قَالُوا: نَعَمْ قَال: فلْيُبَلِّغِ الشاهدُ الغائبَ والسلامُ عليكم
>   ورحمة الله!

Comment: The racial part did look out of place, but would be covered by the part i quoted, right?

Comment: The quoted translation is true to the *spirit* of the sermon, even if it's not a word-to-word translation. So while it didn't specify color of skin, it did cover equality among men despite their racial background.

Comment: Speaking of censorship, it appears that my comment stating that it appears that that spirit doesn't extend to homosexuals and chained boys disappeared.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman - I didn't have a hand in that one, but you have to admit it's off topic. Neither the original sermon or its translations mention anything about homosexuality. That's another topic completely.

Comment: In the Western world of the 20th century, emancipation extended to women, blacks, and gays. Sexual orientation is certainly part of discrimination laws, human rights, and equality. Chaining people, especially black ones, recalls the days of human slavery. The linked Facebook image of the chained black boy sparked this whole equality discussion. It appears that they were right and i was wrong about Islam.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman "spirit doesn't extend to homosexuals" it actually does. I think you didn't pay attention to " except by piety and good action." If someone engages in sodomy he will punished harshly in an Islamic State where Islamic law applies. And if he does that in public (that is, if there are four witnesses), he according to the major fiqhs of Islam will get hanged or stoned to death. There is an exception and that is if the person who committed it is not under the Islamic jurisdiction (e.g, if he is a non-Muslim and his community has a different law than Muslims that have diff sentence).